# How to detect if an app has been removed from a team?

Tags: slack-api

How do I detect if a team has removed my application? Slack doesn't seem to emit an event in such circumstance. Should I just periodically send a request to the https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test endpoint with the oauth tokens I got when they installed the app?

Comment: I am using the solution you mentioned to detect removed application as well. That works and I am not aware of any better alternatives. Would we awesome to have an event for that of course.

Comment: Hi guys any luck with this? Or still using the request to https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test ?